# Symfony 3 join together hours minutes, DateTimeType

Tags: forms, symfony, select, time

I am using the Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;
I want my time field to show hours and minutes in the same drop down select like this:

```
00:00
00:30
01:00
01:30
02.00
02:30
03:00
03:30
```

Any help?

Comment: Could you show us the code that build the form, please? I'm pretty sure that the `TimeType`'s `widget` option set to `choice` can do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Hy, if you just want have the minutes to 00 or 30 you can do in your buildForm :

```
->add('myDate', DateTimeType::class, array(
                 'widget'  => 'choice',
                 'minutes' => array(
                                    0,
                                    30
                                     ),
                 'with_seconds' => false
            ))
```